# I am getting this TypeError which states that cannot destructure property 'db' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, next.js

```
  What does de-structuring mean in this error ?
```

---

```
import dbConnect from '../utils/connectMongoDB'
    
export async function getServerSideProps(context){
const {db} = await dbConnect();
const data = await db.collection("gcompanies").find({});     
const companies = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(companies);
return {
props: { companies :companies },
      }
    }
```

This is my dbConnect.js file

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connect = {};
//this function will check if the connection with database already exists
async function dbConnect() {
  //if its already connected then return
  if (connect.isConnected) {
    return;
  }
  //else connect to the database
  const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  connect.isConnected = true;
}
export default dbConnect;
```

Connection of Next.js with MongoDb is working but I am getting this error while trying to fetch data from MongoDb
Refer this documentation for reference.

Comment: This is what `destructuring` meaning. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
Seems you are trying to destructure `db`. That's the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `dbConnect` function does not return anything.
Also, if you want to access a collection using the standard MongoDB syntax you should use the `mongodb` package.
Try to change its declaration like this:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_URI);

//this function will check if the connection with database already exists
export const dbConnect = async () =>  {
  //if its already connected then return
  if (client.isConnected()) {
    return client.db('<your-database-name>')  
  }
  //else connect to the database
  await client.connect();
  return client.db('<your-database-name>')
}
```

You should then be able to retrieve the `db` object with:

```
import { dbConnect } from '../utils/connectMongoDB';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const db = dbConnect();
  const data = await db.collection('gcompanies').find({});
  const companies = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log(companies);
  return {
    props: { companies: companies },
  };
}
```